# How to draw NSImage to CGContext

Tags: swift, macos

I have an object NSImage, which I want to draw to CGContext.
I found that there is no corresponding method for CGContext, but there seems to be a CGImage method, clip

```
func clip(to: CGRect, mask: CGImage)
```

How do I need to do it, please?

Comment: Convert an NSImge object into an CIImage object.  You can then create a CGContext with it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create an `NSGraphicsContext` wrapping your `CGContext`, and draw into that:

```
let gc: CGContext = ...
let nsImage: NSImage = ...
let rect: CGRect = ...

let priorNsgc = NSGraphicsContext.current
defer { NSGraphicsContext.current = priorNsgc }
NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: gc, flipped: false)
nsImage.draw(in: rect)
```